# Как сделать доступным закрытое поле вложенного класса только во внешнем классе?

Tags: c++

Как сделать доступным закрытое поле вложенного класса только во внешнем классе?

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    private:
        T* bar;
    public:
        //...
    };

    void test(T data)
    {
        B foo(data);
        T* p = foo.bar; //нет доступа
    }
};
```

Comment: переместить класс `B` из публичной в приватную часть, а поле сделать публичным?

Comment: @VladD, нет, `B` должен быть публичным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно класс `A` объявить другом класса `B`:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
        friend class A;  // A друг B

    private:
        T * bar;

    public:
        //...
    };

    void test( T data )
    {
        B foo( data );
        T * p = foo.bar; // доступ есть
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае, у вас проблема в дизайне, причем рекомендации засадить геттер, или, того хуже, устроить дружбу классами, весьма опасны - почитайте Голуба (совет 117), там описано, почему - сделав дружественный класс, вы  дадите *другу* полное право копаться во всех полях *родителя-друга*. Подрыв инкапсуляции налицо.

Если кратко, весь объектно-ориентированный дизайн нужен для управления сложностью путем, в частности, инкапсуляции. А вам ее советуют поломать.

UPD:Ответом на вопрос, в данном случае, является фраза "у вас проблема в дизайне"

Comment: Какая-то параноидальная задача у автора, на практике  проще всего сделать это поле public и не париться.

Comment: Ваша запись не является ответом на вопрос

Comment: @Cerbo позволю себе не согласиться. Дело в том, что наличие дружественных классов или создание наивного публичного метода серьезно нарушают инкапсуляцию. Поэтому, вместо того, чтобы лепить костыли, следует пересмотреть дизайн.

Comment: @gbg: Ваше направление мыслей было бы более понятно, если бы вы не сослались на Голуба (кстати, кто это?), совет номер 53465783, а сформулировали этот совет сами, с аргументацией, для тех, кто ещё не читал и не проникся.

Comment: Хотя да, я тоже чувствую, что friend и потребность в нём не является хорошим дизайном. Но обосновать не могу (с).

Comment: @VladD Голуб - это автор той самой "Веревки достаточной длины, чтобы выстрелить себе в ногу" - сборника правил программирования на C и С++. Обоснование такое - сделав дружественный класс, мы даем другу полное право копаться во всех своих полях. Подрыв инкапсуляции налицо.

Comment: @gbg: ну, вы бы написали это в ответе, мало кто дочитывает до свёрнутых комментариев.

Comment: @VlaD - сделано!

Comment: @gbg: о, спасибо!

Comment: @gdb Вопрос не о том как сделать "правильный" дизайн, вопрос о том какую конструкцию языка применить чтобы сделать поле видимым. Человек не просил ваших оценок "красивасти" дизайна, он задал конкретный технический вопрос. Поэтому ваша запись не ответ, а личное мнение.